# React nested module shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: Nav is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I have started to learn `ReactJs`, I dont have any idea how to debug this. I have a basic `app.jsx` .

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory} = require('react-router');
var Main = require('Main');
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>

        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I have written two basic components in my React app now and I nested them.

```
var React = require('react');

React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <h2>Nav Component</h2>
        );
    }
})

module.exports = Nav;
var React = require('react');
var Nav = require('Nav');

var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Nav/>
                <h2>Main Component</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = Main;
```

I use webpack

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        root: __dirname,
        alias: {
            Main: 'app/components/Main.jsx',
            Nav: 'app/components/Nav.jsx'
        },
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'] 
                },
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude:/(node_modules|bower_components)/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

and I dont get any errors but browser shows nothing. When I check developer tools I see `"Uncaught ReferenceError: Nav is not defined"`.The files are in correct folders. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code you’ve provided is accurate, the problem is that you didn’t actually define a variable called `Nav` in your nav file. You just called `React.createClass` without assigning that to the variable `Nav`. Then you tried to export `Nav` at the bottom. Assign your `createClass` calls to variables and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi because your component definition is wrong it could be like below 
class Nav  extends React.Component or var Nav = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (

### Nav Component

);
    }
})